# How to get SQLite.net to work with Mono Android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am successfully using SQLite-net (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) in my MonoTouch project. However when I try to use the same in Mono Android, the Database call throws an exception in the Prepare2 method.

I am using the SQLite-Net file as-is in my Android project.
Do I need to make any changes specific for MonoAndroid?

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This blog post](http://www.gregshackles.com/2011/02/using-a-database-in-monodroid-applications/) has some details on how to use SQLite-net in a Mono for Android application. I also recommend checking out the [MWC application created by Xamarin](http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/02/24/mwc_2012/) which is a good recent example of using the library in an application.

If you still run into problems, please provide some details on what the problem is (exception type/text, stacktrace, etc).

Comment: That's exactly the blog post I referred to. I am not using the helper class but I cant get the stack trace. It just says SQL Result Error. I wonder if its a reference issue.